# Nuget error: 'EntityFramework 5.0.0' is not compatible with 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework 1.0.0

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, nuget, unity-container

I've just created a Web API application for .Net 4.5 to do some tests with Unity (IoC framework)*.

I've added Unity using Nuget:

```
Install-Package Unity
```

Then I've added Mvc5 support

```
Install-Package Unity.Mvc5
```

For the backend, I created a class project with an EF model in it, with minimal content. I registered it like this:

```
container.RegisterType<MyEntities>();
```

To do a basic process test, I added a repository and registered it like so:

```
container.RegisterType<IMyRepository, MyRepository>();
```

As far as I can tell everything is up and running, but when I execute, I get the notification that the Web API misses a reference to EF 5.

So I try add it like this:

```
Install-Package EntityFramework -Version 5.0.0
```

But then I get this error:

> Unable to resolve dependencies. 'EntityFramework 5.0.0' is not
>   compatible with 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework 1.0.0
>   constraint

The `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework` reference was added during Web API project creation and it's (strangely) actually version 2.0!

I want to leave the project as is, because I think the above reference is for authentication? And I will be needing that at some point.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

- I want to test registering an EF ObjectContext as a dependency, see my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33544423/ioc-unity-registering-an-entity-framework-objectcontext-for-dependency-injectio/33544631?noredirect=1#comment54872362_33544631).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asp Identity Entity Framework 2 has dependency to Entity Framework version 6.0.1 and above.

[See documentation](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework/)

Update your entity framework to latest version and then try your code.

> Update-Package EntityFramework -version 6.1.3

Comment: That works, thanks! A bonus question if I may: I think Unity is set up correctly but I'm getting a 'no parameterless constructor' error for the homecontroller (which takes the IMyRepository as dependency). I added the container to the WebApiConfig, do I need to register it elsewhere as well (Owin perhaps)?

Comment: See this link. I hope that it will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9527988/cannot-inject-dependencies-into-asp-net-web-api-controller-using-unity